# How to setup an FTP server on Linux that will use an API for authentication rather that a static list of users?

Tags: linux, ftp, authentication, http

I'd like to have an FTP server on a Unix machine that will be able to query a certain API (probably via HTTP or local shell script) in order to authenticate the client.

It would be enough if there is a server that can handle the scenario below:

1. Client connects via FTP to my server
2. Client sends the username and password
3. Server executes a local script with the given parameter
4. (my custom logic inside the script)
5. Return a success/failure code/message back to the FTP server

Is there such a server on the market? Or is it possible to customize some of the existing servers to cover the scenario above?

---

*Note 1*: I see that [vsftpd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) offers a module for virtual users, but it's not quite clear (to me) how to setup such a module with a custom (eg: HTTP) API

*Note 2*: There seem to be some ways to build ([in C](https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam)) PAM modules, but I'm hoping for an easier way (that will allow me to configure the authentication mechanism rather than building a C library).

*Note 3*: In regards to the question being put on hold: please note that this question focuses mainly on a means through which FTP authentication can be achieved using a custom protocol/API. I'm not looking for a specific product, but I'm trying to solve a specific problem. Obviously, a product is needed to implement such a solution since we're dealing with a FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems **Pure-FTPD** is what you need. Here are two points from their 'About' section seems exactly matching to your needs:

- Multiple authentication methods can be chained in any order. For instance, SQL accounts, LDAP directories and system accounts can be used at the same time.
- Custom authentication methods can easily be added. Pure-FTPd supports external authentication modules, and writing a new backend can be as simple as a few lines of shell script.

Further info: https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look into Pure-FTPD and I'll come back with a reply if it fits my needs.